# How to reduce noise while recording with AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am using AudioKit to record audio and display visualizer while recording and playing audio. 
It works good, But recorded audio has lots of background noise.

Is there any way to reduce noise? 
Here is the code for prepare recording

```
func prepareForRecording() {
    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    // Patching
    outputPlot.node = mic
    micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
    micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)

    // Microphone monitoring is muted
    micBooster.gain = 0 // Silent
    recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)
    if let file = recorder?.audioFile {
        player = try? AKAudioPlayer(file:file)
    }
    player?.completionHandler = playingEnded

    moogLadder = AKMoogLadder(player)

    mainMixer = AKMixer(moogLadder, micBooster)

    AudioKit.output = mainMixer

    if isMicPresent {
        AudioKit.stop()
        AudioKit.start()
    }
    currentSeconds = 0
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, lots of crackling sounds. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this code: uses AudioKit and does some smooting and filtering:  https://github.com/comyar/TuningFork

Comment: hint: low pass filter