# Filtering background noise frequency

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, audiokit

I would like to ask if it is possible to filter the frequency of the human voice only via AudioKit or otherwise. I want to create an emotional analyzer based on these frequencies from a human voice, but the problem is that the microphone captures all the frequencies around me. Is there any way to remove this?

And next, I would like to ask if it is possible to recognize which one is just talking. I mean conversation between two people.

Thank you in advance for a possible answer.

Comment: What research have you done before you posted the question?

Comment: This is a very difficult ask as the human voice itself has many important frequencies, especially if you consider how it changes due to emotion. I'm sure you'll have to do some serious research and specialized DSP to get close to such a task.

Comment: @Tobi I spent 3 days searching for an answer, but I have always found only the option to remove background noise, but not frequency filtering in the background.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Thank you for your answer, so I will try to find a solution :-)

Comment: probably duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507343/how-to-reduce-noise-while-recording-with-audiokit

Comment: @mahaltertin No, there asking only for background noise reduction, but not background noise "frequency" filtering or ignoring. I see this post before :-)