# Recording voice while playing music - filter speakers input (iOS)

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, audiokit

I am developing an **Karaoke app** in which you can record your voice while listening to the music. When user uses headphones, everything is great - he can listen to the music and himself in headphones while singing. Then we have his pure voice recorded and we can mix it with playback.
Problem occurs when user does not use headphones. Then we play music via speakers `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and record simultaneously. In final recording we have user's voice and playback from speakers mixed together. Problem is that playback's volume is very big and it's "covering" user's voice. Firstly I thought that this is normal behaviour  because speakers are close to `microphone` so there is nothing I can do.
However when I tried the same thing on Garage Band it somehow lowers playback from speakers making voice more hearable.
I also tried it with Instagram (you can record while playing music e.g. from Spotify) and I noticed that after ~1 sec. playback's volume is decreasing and we can hear voice more precisely.
I don't think that it's post processing because it would be very complicated so maybe there is an option to let "iOS handle it".
To be clear - it does not lowers playback during recording - it's "done" while listening final video.

I use `AVCaptureSession` for recording and `AudioKit Player` for playing.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/tips/advices!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I asked Apple TS and the respond was exactly what I wanted: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/mode/1616455-voicechat You just have to set this mode in AVAudioSession and system will handle it `device’s tonal equalization is optimized for voice`

Answer (score 1):

iOS cannot 'just handle' that, there is no "filter out the music" function. The fact that it doesn't do it live, but does so later or with a delay strongly implies they are doing some post processing. I'm not a machine learning expert, but I think if you just used an equalizer and a noise gate you could get this effect. It'd be hard to extract an acapella but you could certainly improve it. Likely Instagram takes that second to identify where the voice frequencies are so it knows how to EQ the signal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am really not sure that it is some kind of post processing. We tried EQ and other filters on Logic and we could not properly distinguish voice even manually on 1 recording. iPhone uses this mechanism during call - it tries to remove all background noise so that voice will be more hearable.

Comment: "tries to remove all background noise". Noise reduction is exactly what you are trying to do. 
There is another question very much like this one, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507343/how-to-reduce-noise-while-recording-with-audiokit?rq=1 and in the comments there the guy links this code. https://github.com/comyar/TuningFork
If you find a magical "remove music from sounds" function call LMK, I would also find it very useful ;).

Comment: Consider the team of people working on Garageband - these are sound heavies.

Comment: Thanks again for reply. What was the most interesting thing for me was this case with Instagram - it was able to reduce volume of other's app music (but after recording). I thought it might be using: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616618-duckothers I did not test it but it will probably just lower volume during recording not after. Nevertheless it looks like there is nothing I can do about this issue.

Comment: Ah, I can see why you might think that. A good example of ducking is when a character speaks in a movie. There might be things on fire, gunshots, engines, whatever - but when the character speaks, these other sound channels (imagine a mixer) are reduced in volume so you can hear the character. it's a playback thing not a recording thing.

Comment: I tested my app multiple times and here are 2 results: 1) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WvMg2JYaIudNlnYQGhw4oNvbwMfQpiFV
2) https://drive.google.com/open?id=17rXN8ml-BwB3RaBbWu05ZGOeOk1nSHyD
Both of these recordings were done in the same conditions, with the same volume, on the same iPhone. Amplitude of my voice is also almost the same. As you can hear - on 2) at 3th second playback lowers volume and my voice is hearable (I didn't lower volume during recording). On 1) you can't hear my voice. The only difference is that on 2) I start talking immediately, on 1) i start after few seconds.

Comment: What libraries / objects / SDKs are you using for your recording ? You may have to go lower into the audio stack to find what you are looking for.

Comment: As mention above - I use pure `AVCaptureSession` for recording - something like https://medium.com/@santhosh3386/ios-avcapturesession-record-video-with-audio-23c8f8c9a8f8