# How to add a music background in the video chat on iOS?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have a question about the AVAudioPlayer and its AVAudioSessionCategory parameter.

So, basically, I have a video chat between two users and I want to play music as a background for them. I tried to use the "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord" value for the AVAudioSessionCategory, but in that case, the music will be recorded and send together with the voice to the partner.

I think that I'm looking for a way to play music but do not record it, so each partner will be listening to its own music.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the result and what part need assistance with?

Comment: I tried to use these values for AVAudioSessionCategory: playAndRecord (in that case music will be sent to the partner), playback (the voice won't be recorded). Is it even possible to play music and record only the voice without the music?

Comment: Something like this, but I don't need the music to be recorded at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442132/recording-voice-while-playing-music-filter-speakers-input-ios